# How to make a HTML table that has two rowspan column?

Tags: html

I am confused and cannot make a table like this in HTML:

[image]

I make the HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="1">

<!-- Header -->
<tr>
<th rowspan="3">Name</th>
<th rowspan="3">Button</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Details</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
<th>First name</th> 
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>

<!-- Content -->

<tr>
<td>Bonds</td>
<td><input value="click me!" type="button"/>    </td>
<td>James</td>
<td>Bonds</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mary</td>
<td><input value="click me!" type="button"/></td>
<td>Mary</td>
<td>Jane</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
```

But, the "button" column is always next to the "Name" column, it is not like that I want. How to make it like that?

Comment: where do you want the buttons to be  ?? at the end or below

Comment: same as the image

Comment: do you wish to do some action like...export the data on click..or edit the record ..?? where is the data for the table coming from ?

Comment: you are making things more complicated.

Comment: no I was about to suggest jquery datatable ....which has more functions thn HTML table...you might not need it right now...but may be latter you would see the full picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="1">

<!-- Header -->
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Details</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Button</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>First name</th> 
    <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>

<!-- Content -->

<tr>
<td>Bonds</td>
<td>James</td>
<td>Bonds</td>
<td><input value="click me!" type="button"/>   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mary</td>
<td>Mary</td>
<td>Jane</td>
<td><input value="click me!" type="button"/></td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some CSS to make the button fill the entire TD..it looks better

```
 input { 
   width:96%;
   padding:0 2%; 
}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3pzymLa/)